# plotHR (package Greg) - Spline-Plot - Manually set Hazard ratio = 1 to according x-Value

Tags: r, plot, statistics, spline, survival-analysis

I got a question concerning the "centering" of the spline-plot.
Which value does plotHR take as Hazard ratio=1?
Is it possible to for example assign Hazard ratio 1 to the median age(or average age) when using coxph-function?
Is it possible to manually choose the x-axis-value( e.g. age) which ist being associated with the y-axis-value Hazard ratio= 1 when using the coxph function and pspline?

plotHR is included in the Greg package.
The example below ist a slightly modified version of this plotHR-example: https://rdrr.io/cran/Greg/man/plotHR.html

The code below will assign the Hazard ratio of 1 to a x-axis value somewhere between median age an 3rd Quartile. How can I assign the median age to hazard ratio 1?

```
library(Greg)
library(survival)
library(rms)
# Get data for example
n <- 1000
set.seed(731)
age <- c(rnorm(50, mean=20, sd=1), round(50 + 12*rnorm(900), 1),rnorm(50, mean=80, sd=1))
label(age) <- "Age"
sex <- factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n,
                     rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4)))
cens <- c(17*runif(n-60),1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
smoking <- factor(sample(c('Yes','No'), n,
                         rep=TRUE, prob=c(.2, .75)))
h <- .02*exp(.02*(age-50)+.1*((age-50)/10)^3+.8*(sex=='Female')+2*(smoking=='Yes'))
dt <- -log(runif(n))/h
label(dt) <- 'Follow-up Time'
e <- ifelse(dt <= cens,1,0)
dt <- pmin(dt, cens)
units(dt) <- "Year"
# Add missing data to smoking
smoking[sample(1:n, round(n*0.05))] <- NA
# Create a data frame since plotHR will otherwise
# have a hard time getting the names of the variables
ds <- data.frame(
  dt = dt,e = e,
  age=age,
  smoking=smoking,
  sex=sex)
library(splines)
Srv <- Surv(dt,e)
org_par <- par(xaxs="i", ask=TRUE)
dd <- datadist(ds)
options(datadist='dd')
fit.cph <- coxph(Srv ~ pspline(age,4) + sex + smoking, data=ds, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
unadjusted_fit <- coxph(Srv ~ pspline(age,4), data=ds, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
plotHR(list(fit.cph, unadjusted_fit), term="age", xlab="Age",
       polygon_ci=c(TRUE, FALSE),
       col.term = c("#08519C", "#77777799"),
       col.se = c("#DEEBF7BB", grey(0.6)),
       lty.term = c(1, 2),
       plot.bty="l", xlim=c(30, 90),rug="ticks")
par(org_par)
```

The result of the code above ist the following plot (the red box was added manually in order to show that HR=1 an median age are not assigned to one another):
[Resulting Spline-Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNCt5.png)

Comment: When I try to specify the median by using the command cntrst = median(age) i get the following error:  `Error in prPhEstimate(model = model, ylog = ylog, cntrst = cntrst, xlim = xlim,  : 
  Contrast plotting is not defined for the models of class 'coxph.penal', 'coxph'`

Comment: Obviously someone got a similar question which has unfortunately not been answered yet: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410713/contrast-in-plothr-for-spline-hr-plot

Answer (score 0):

The contrast only works with `rms` ouputs, i.e.

```r
fit.cph <- cph(Srv ~ rcs(age, 3) + sex + smoking, data=ds, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
unadjusted_fit <- cph(Srv ~ rcs(age, 3), data=ds, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
plotHR(list(fit.cph, unadjusted_fit), term="age", xlab="Age",
       polygon_ci=c(TRUE, FALSE),
       col.term = c("#08519C", "#77777799"),
       col.se = c("#DEEBF7BB", grey(0.6)),
       lty.term = c(1, 2),
       cntrst = TRUE,
       plot.bty="l", xlim=c(30, 90),rug="ticks")
```

Note that the contrast is by default the median, see the `forestplot:::prPhNewData` function with the attribute.